# msbuild and searching for text

Tags: msbuild

I have a msbuild task that outputs to a file.

Now I want to search that file for a certain text or regex expression and return true if it is there and false if it isn't

any idea of a task that could do this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using MSBuild 4 (with Visual Studio 2010), you can use [Property Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440%28VS.100%29.aspx) and do this without any custom task:

```
<IsMyFileMatching>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch($([System.File]::ReadAllText("yourfile"), "pattern")))</IsMyFileMatching>
```

Comment: Sweet - didn't know about this.